# How to use ( Super Kleer ) for the Beer !

Tags: fermentation, beer, bottling, techniques, secondary-fermentation

How to use ( Super Kleer ) to clear the beer ... I purchased that but i didn't find a clear Direction to use it for the Beer ... Is it during primary or secondary ! 
Im planning to use it in the secondary fermentation & 2 days before bottling.

Any ideas !

Comment: Why not let the beer clear naturally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Super Kleer, you should use it when primary fermentation is done, so during secondary. Put first the D1 packet to the wort, stir, then mix the D2 packet with 30ml of warm water and add it to the wort, then after 12-48h your beer should be clear.

Usually, this kind of clarifying agent is not necessary for beer, using irish moss at the end of boiling is suffisant.